# popping a stack out of a stack/queue

Tags: c#, stack, queue

My question is about how to get a stack out of a queue. The program should work by generating stacks (shown below), having those stacks stuffed with data (also shown below), then unloading and displaying the data in them. Right now it just throws a CS1061 exception at me. The 5 is there for example, the actual code is picking a random string from an array.

```
    public void newCustomers()
    {
        var customer = new Stack();
        store.Enqueue(customer);
    }
    public void Shop()
    {
        var customer = store.Dequeue();
        customer.Push(5);
        //^currently this doesn't work. I'm assuming the typing for customer is wrong.
        store.Enqueue(customer);
    }
```

CS1061

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Push' and no accessible extension method 'Push' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have no idea what a CS1061 is off the top of my head.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the error message.

Comment: Are you missing the type for `new Stack()`?  Shouldn't it be `new Stack<int>()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the non-generic `Queue` class. The `Dequeue()` method returns an `object` that you would have to cast to `Stack`:

```
var customer = (Stack)store.Dequeue();
customer.Push(5);
```

I would suggest using the generic queue class `Queue<T>` instead.